# C# return IWebElement (selenium) causes NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, methods

I am new to C# and working with methods. My attempt was to create a seperate method for logging the user in. The Code looks something like

```
public IWebDriver bot;


void DataGrabber(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string user = "...";
    string pass = "...";

    UserLogin(user, pass);

    bot.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://example.com/data"); //NullReferenceException gets raised here
}

static IWebDriver UserLogin(string user, string pass)
{
    IWebDriver bot = new ChromeDriver();
    
    bot.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://example.com/loginform");
    // Login Stuff....
    return bot;

}
```

how do I properly define bot, so that the DataGrabber() method knows what it is?

I removed the `public IWebDriver bot;` definition in the beginning but that just results in the bot not being recognized as a variable at all ("The name "bot" is not available in the current context").

I also attempted to move the UserLogin() method before the DataGrabber() method, but this did not help (bot still not recognized within DataGrabber() function).

I am certain that this is an easy thing to answer, however searching online did not return anything useful

Comment: You never assign anything to the field `bot`. `async void` is a bug too, as such methods can't be awaited. There's nothing asynchronous in that method either. The `async void` signature is *only* meant for asynchronous event handlers. `async` doesn't make a method asynchronous, it tells the compiler to generate the code needed to use `await` to await asynchronous calls

Comment: Selenium doesn't have asynchronous methods so the only way to avoid blocking when making Selenium calls is to use `Task.Run`. If you really want asynchronous calls, check Playwright

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return (the local variable) `bot` from `UserLogin`, but you never assign it to the class-level field. In other words: the `bot` in UserLogin is different from the `bot` in DataGrabber.

One solution:

in DataGrabber, change

```
UserLogin(user, pass);
```

to

```
bot = UserLogin(user, pass);
```

to set the class-level field.

For further details about that exception, see [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: There's an `async void` bug too.

Comment: I didn't notice it but the parameters suggest an event handler - the only place async void is valid

Comment: Selenium has no async methods, so even if `DataGrabber` is an unconventionally named event handler, it won't run asynchronously